# Como enumerar uma coluna com update?

Tags: php, sql

Tenho as seguintes colunas:

```
Usuário | Ranking | Posição 
Fulano      300        1
Ciclano     400        2 
Beltrano    500        3
```

Eu queria saber como colocar essa  posição 1 2 3... sem ser manual como eu faço e sim através de um comando SQL,  sempre somando 1 a mais para ficar em ordem: 1 2 3 4 5... e tem que ser de acordo com o ranking, quem tem ranking menor fica com as primeiras posições

Eu preciso de um comando `update` que faça isso, pois toda semana terei que alterar as posições.

Eu tentei usar o `DECLARE @contador = 1`, mas eu não consegui usar esse comando no SQL. Deu erro esse seguinte erro:

> Unrecognized statement type. (near "DECLARE").

Estou fazendo pelo phpMyAdmin. Alguém poderia me ajudar como fazer isso?

Comment: Qual SQL você está usando? MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL... ?

Comment: Porque você precisa salvar a posição se já tem o ranking, que é o que a define? Não seria melhor resolver isso na aplicação?

Comment: Estou usando phpmyadmin do cpanel. Não entendo muito sobre isso. Ajuda?

Comment: Não sei se vai entender mais: é que estou contando a linha de colunas e essa contagem é a qual é os números dos rankings 1,2,3... e aí depois eu uso um if para que de acordo com o ranking da semana passada e dessa semana, ele mostre se continuou estável, ou caiu ou subiu no ranking, preenchendo manualmente a coluna ranking. Exemplo: na coluna ranking, a pessoa está na posição 2, e na contagem das colunas ela está na posição 1, então ela subiu... Não sei se deu pra entender, mas o meu problema é que eu queria inserir na tabela ranking os valores em ordem 1,2,3... sem ser manualmente.